# Unsupported PNaCl bitcode version

Tags: google-nativeclient

After upgrading Google Chrome, I can no longer run my pnacl application:

```
NativeClient: NaCl module load failed: PnaclCoordinator: PNaCl Translator Error: Unsupported PNaCl bitcode version: 1
```

Google Chrome version: 31.0.1650.0 dev

nacl sdk version: pepper_30 (dev)

pnacl-translate works:

```
pnacl-translate application.pexe -arch i686 -o application.nexe
```

It is unfortunate that you don't get a more helpful error message. Any suggestions what might be wrong here?

**chrome://nacl** shows:

```
About NaCl

Google Chrome 31.0.1650.0 (dev) 
OS Mac OS X 

NaCl plugin /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/31.0.1650.0/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Internet Plug-Ins/ppGoogleNaClPluginChrome.plugin 

Portable Native Client (PNaCl) Enabled 
PNaCl translator path /Users/peter/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/pnacl/0.1.0.12181/_platform_specific/x86_32 
PNaCl translator version 0.1.0.12180 

Native Client (non-portable, outside web store) Enabled by flag '--enable-nacl'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem, as the translator version was upgraded for Chrome 31 to accept a newer version of the PNaCl bitcode. To solve this, build your `.pexe` with the latest SDK.

More details in [this email thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/native-client-discuss/On5zhJ9RQzo).

Comment: Thank you!

pepper_31 isn't available in the *naclsdk list*. Is there a way to download it "manually"?

Comment: @PeterB: `pepper_canary` should work for you. That would be the easiest way IMHO. Other than that you're always free to clone and build the NaCl SDK - http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient-sdk/ - it's an open-source project, after all :)